# What kind of freewheel/cassette is this?

Tags: cassette, freewheel

I bought some old bike from netherlands, I wanted to restore it.
Rear wheel is broken and I wanted to exchange it but there is this strange freewheel which I cannot identify, do you have any idea what it is?
[image: Freewheel][image: Rear wheel and freewheel]

Comment: @sashir please don't take the duplicate flag as being an attack on you - instead it shows that the same question has already been asked and answered, so to avoid duplicating effort, this question gets pointed at the original.   IE, "here's one we prepared earlier"

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't noticed this one, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

It's called a Helicomatic. The idea was to make a freewheel that does not need a lockring that has to be torqued tight. The helical splines make the freewheel tighten itself.

Amazingly we had this exact question about a month ago, so I flagged this as a duplicate question.